# What is the best way to schedule file upload in android?

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I am developing an app in which I am taking some pictures along with some info and then uploading the whole to the server. I am uploading the file in response to a button click but it only happens when internet is working fine. So I want to schedule the date uploading task for later in the case if internet do not work and want to automatically upload it to the server as soon as the device get connected to the internet.

I have gone through JobScheduler API but the problem is it doesn't support Android device lower than 5.0(API 21) and my requirement is to build this app down to API 17. Hence need your suggestions and any API for the same.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into using `ConnectivityManager` for monitoring the [Monitoring the Connectivity Status](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)? You can receive a broadcast event when wifi is available and resume/start your upload.

> From the Android Docs:

**Determine if You Have an Internet Connection**

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

**Determine the Type of your Internet Connection**

```
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

**Monitor for Changes in Connectivity**

The ConnectivityManager broadcasts the `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION ("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")` action whenever the connectivity details have changed. You can register a broadcast receiver in your manifest to listen for these changes and resume (or suspend) your background updates accordingly.

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
```

Changes to a device's connectivity can be very frequent—this broadcast is triggered every time you move between mobile data and Wi-Fi. As a result, it's good practice to monitor this broadcast only when you've previously suspended updates or downloads in order to resume them. It's generally sufficient to simply check for Internet connectivity before beginning an update and, should there be none, suspend further updates until connectivity is restored.

This technique requires toggling broadcast receivers you've declared in the manifest, which is described in the next lesson.

Here's another good resource:

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-getting-notified-of-connectivity-changes/